# How can i show my pdf file on ipad application

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, pdf

i want to create simple pdf reader application for ipad.
but did not find the proper documentation or sample code. please guide me from where i should  start.

Thanks

Miraaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uiwebview *web;

[self.web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"senthil" ofType:@"pdf"]]]];
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use a UIWebView. WebKit can display PDF natively.

If you need to render the PDF yourself not relying on WebKit, check the CGPDF*** stuff (search for it in Xcode docs).

Answer (score 1):

You can find a nice app sample with CC license on [this repository](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)

I hope it helps. It definitely helped me

Answer (score 0):

You should start at the [iPhone Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action).